# How to pass a textbox value to child page textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

(all in wpf)

I have a login window with username and password. When a user logs in, the value of the username is passed on to another username.text textbox in the MainWindow. This I have successfully done by passing a string value in the form declaration. Same way you normally would in winforms.

Now the way i access my child pages are through links.

e.g: Link DisplayName= "Home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml" /> so child pages content are shown on the main window. as if the main window is a frame of some sort.

What I need now is that this username.text in the MainWindow has its value passed on to username.text textboxes in the child pages.

I am doing this so that the program will know which user is logging in ang can log who is making what changes to the database.

I understand that the most efficient method od doing this is through one way databinding.
now this works in the same page... but it doesn't work in a different page and main window.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=alias, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="alias" Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>
```

Is there anyone that knows how to do this?

code for the MainWindow

```
    <mui:ModernWindow x:Class="Masca.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    Title="Masca Database Admin" Height="800" Width="1280" IsTitleVisible="True"
    LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"          
    ContentSource="/Pages/Home.xaml">

<Window.DataContext>
    <TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=alias, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

code for the child page

```
  <UserControl x:Class="Masca.Mail.Configuration"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1280">



<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="780" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1260">

    <TextBox x:Name="alias" Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>


</Grid>
```

that's the xaml for both the mainwindow and child page.

Comment: Is the data Context for MainWindow and child page same? if not then make it same by making ViewModel SingleTon instance.

Comment: by data context yo mean:  <Window.DataContext> yes? user name sits between those two opening and closing tags but the child page has none. am i supposed to do something with it?

Comment: Oh.. sorry. Just understood. Trying now.

Comment: Okay I've been doing some googling and i have to say what I found didnt seem to work. there doesnt seem to be many examples of the SingleTon instance. Just opinions I just added the rest of the xaml. any idea on what I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you View model Expose static property as below

```
public class ViewModel
{
  private static ViewModel instance=new ViewModel();

  public static Viewmodel Instance
  {
     get
     {
        return instance;
     }
  }
}
```

And in both the Xmal.cs(MainWindow.xmal.cs and ChildPage.Xmal.cs files in Constructor set the data context

```
    DataContext=Viewmodel.Instance
```

And change TextBinding in both Xmal as follows

```
  <TextBox x:Name="username" Text="{Binding PropertyInViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11"/>

  <TextBox x:Name="alias" Text="{Binding PropertyInViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>
```

Comment: I'm probably gonna come off as as anoying at this point. The static property, does it go on both pages? and by constructor, you mean the form declaration with the "initializecomponent()"?

Comment: Okay I just figured out that i have to create one... How on earth does one do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a static class

```
public static class Credentials
{
    public static string username { get; set;}
}
```

Assign it during logon then you may call it in a base VM class or on each clase you need.